# Хранение данных о пользователе (ACL) в Session

Tags: php, сессия, acl

В общем суть вопроса такова:
Есть два и более приложений написанных на PHP Phalcon

- example.com (Лэндинг)
- auth.example.com (Авторизация)
- office.example.com (виртуальный офис)
- blog.example.com (блог)

Для каждого приложения отдельная база данных.

Необходимо при переходе на определенную страницу например в office.example.com проверялись права пользователя (user, admin, menager и т.д)
Так как все данные о пользователе хранятся в отдельной БД на auth.example.com нужно придумать интерфейс получения данных.
Использовать API не вариант так как не смог найти наглядных примеров JWT возможно плохо искал...
Решил использовать такой вариант:
При авторизации на auth.example.com создается сессия и cookies для всех под доменов системы.

Могу ли я в сессии хранить все необходимую мне информацию о группе пользователя, безопасно ли это?
Может есть другие варианты подхода?

Спасибо!

Comment: вы только что изобрели микросервисы)

Comment: Разве микросервисы общаются не по API?

Comment: сессия храниться на сервере. а вот кука на стороне клиента. соответственно, хранение в сессии - безопасно (если конечно клиент не взломает сервер и не получит доступ), а вот куки - нет.